# Wordpress - Upload media to different server

Tags: wordpress

I've split the resources on a WP site into two servers: Server A with administration files, Server B with public files. They are connected by the data base.

Are there any way that will cause media that I upload from the WP admin installation on Server A to be stored over on Server B? Whit this, that media will be served from Server B ("public site").

If possible, other than through an FTP connection, my client doesn't want a FTP in the public site :-(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a remote storage service where you can post the file and return a URL addressing the file on server B. Then you can use wp filters to attain the url from server A.

You can hook into this filter: "wp_handle_upload"

```
    apply_filters{
      'wp_handle_upload'
       array( 'file' => $new_file, 'url' => $url, 'type' => $type ), 'upload' 
     )
```

just replace the URL to the new one

Comment: Where do you place the credentials of the other server?

Comment: This method does not require credentials. Look up "POST method file uploads". You need to setup your server accordingly, this will be Cross Domain so you would need to get around that somehow (CORS,AMF or cross-domain XHR). The easier way is to do FTP upload using something like: ftp_put($conn_id, $server_path, $file, FTP_BINARY)

Comment: Any chance you can update your answer and elaborate a little?